# I have a task to write a recursive function to print all the numbers of an array whose indexes are prime numbers

Tags: arrays, c, function, recursion, primes

I have a task to write a recursive function to print all the numbers of an array whose indexes are prime numbers.

Actually, I can understand recursion, but I can't get in for void functions.

This is my code and I can't understand how to write if statement correctly to print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 void prime(int arr[], int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return; //there are no elements
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; ++i)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            break;
        else
            printf("Number %d has a prime index %d.", arr[n], n);
    }
    prime(arr + 1, n - 1);
}



int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    prime(arr[100], 100);
}
```

Comment: You used `==` in the second `if` statement, why didn't you in the first `if` statement?

Comment: You seem to have left out the part that prints the prime numbers.  Or are you supposed to print the elements of the array where the index is a prime number?

Comment: How many times does the loop `for (int i = 0; i > n; ++i)` execute?  The `>` should be `<`, should it not?  Also, when `i` is zero, `n % i` is going to give you a 'divide by zero' error, which normally stops your program forcibly.

Comment: I think one function shouldn't have many functionality, if you have to write all stuff in a function I think you should have a flag for check prime number. One more think that for loop should start from 2 to n/2

Comment: Using 2 to n/2 is a major improvement, @ĐăngKhôi, but you can do better still with `for (i = 2; i <= n / i; i++)` which places the upper bound at √n, which is generally even better.  There are many other ways to improve the primality testing (only test 2 and odd numbers, only test 2 and 3 and numbers of the form 6N±1, etc).

Comment: In your printf statement you use ‘n’ where I think you mean to use ‘i’.

Answer (score 0):

While passing arrays we always pass its name and not its name
with size.

If we pass `arr[100]`, it actually passes the element at 100th index which is out of bounds (as array will start at 0 and end at index 99).

[You can refer here](https://newton.ex.ac.uk/teaching/resources/jmr/6-goodbad.html) for more details.

```
prime(arr, 100);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).